# SwiftyJSON how to correctly access variables?

Tags: swift, variables, properties, swifty-json

I try to figure out SwiftyJSON but I'm facing a problem

The code shown below works fine

```
 import UIKit     
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json")
            var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
            if data != nil {
            let hoge = JSON(data: data!)
            let count = hoge["results"][0]["body"]
            println(count)
            }
    }}
```

but when i try to add a method which accesses the hoge it returns nothing

code looks like this

```
 func res() {
  dump(hoge)
 }
```

I tried to declare `let hoge` and `let count` in the `header` of `ViewController`, but it always gives errors.

How to do it correctly, so i can access array thorough all the code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Declare `huge` using `var` not `let` (as well as `count` too) and then try again

Comment: app builds, but dump still not executes

Comment: Where have called the function `res()` ??

Comment: at the bottom after viewDidLoad https://www.evernote.com/l/AAuREXKnDyVOD6ky4Rdri89B-rw4d9wvcqo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare a variable inside a function, like you do here in `viewDidLoad`, this variable is *only* available in the same scope, meaning that variable doesn't exist outside `viewDidLoad`. Actually it is even deallocated (destroyed) when the function execution finishes.

The solution is to create `var hoge: JSON?` at the root of your class, outside any function, then only assign the JSON value to this variable when it is available:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var hoge: JSON?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.whitehouse.gov/v1/petitions.json")
            var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
            if data != nil {
                hoge = JSON(data: data!)
                let count = hoge!["results"][0]["body"]
                println(count)
            }
    }}
```

That way you can also create other methods that can access `hoge` outside of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: yes, i tryed that, and there are 2 options - if i declare var hoge: JSON? i got an error https://www.evernote.com/l/AAuyL7xqZXdJKKU5JPTYEsJ5auJ5hDNVsn8 and if i comment out let count and println(count) dump still not executes

Comment: Look at my example, you missed the `!` just after `hoge`: `let count = hoge!["results"][0]["body"]`. As we declare `hoge` as an Optional, you have to either force unwrap it with `!` or to use optional binding with `if let ...`

Comment: This is another question for another problem. You don't even show the content of your `dump` function. Better ask a new question for the new topic, with details about this `dump` function, etc. :)

Comment: I have shown - in question https://www.evernote.com/l/AAs9SgcIxJJPv6YoNAJVFB43a5nmUW4lgGE

Comment: Nope, in the screenshot I see the content of `res`, not of `dump`. I don't know what `dump` is. And this is another question anyway, your original question "I tried to declare let hoge and let count in the header of ViewController, but i always get errors. How to do it correctly, so i can access array thorough all the code ?" has been answered. :)

Comment: dump is array function from apple documentation inside res(). unfortunatelly stackoverflow doesnt let me create another topic in 90 minutes :(

Comment: Ask a new question about why Apple's `dump` function doesn't work with your code *that now works but didn't before and has been fixed here*. And ask it in 90 minutes if the site says so, where's the problem? You *will* have answers then, don't worry. :)